rust, sqlite and self referential struct
I'm new to Rust and facing some issue with what I learnt is called "self-referential structs", though not because I absolutely want to define a self referential struct but because a lib I'm using seems to force me into this design.
I started using the sqlite crate to store some data in a db. Wanting to abstract a little bit the design, I extracted the sqlite code into a separate class (let's call it SqliteController) :
pub struct SqliteController {
    con: sqlite::Connection,
}

impl SqliteController {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> SqliteController {
        let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
        Self::create_schema(&con);
        SqliteController { con: con }
    }
...

so far so good, but it was a naive impl and very slow, so let's use prepared statements then !
This works :
use sqlite::State;

pub struct PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    _con: &'conn sqlite::Connection,
    some_statement: sqlite::Statement<'conn>,
}

impl<'conn> PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    pub fn new(con: &sqlite::Connection) -> PreparedSqliteController {
        Self::create_schema(con);

        PreparedSqliteController {
            _con: con,
            some_statement: con.prepare("SELECT xxx;").unwrap(),
        }
    }

    pub fn create_schema(_con: &sqlite::Connection)  {}

    pub fn exec_some_statement(&mut self) {
        while let Ok(State::Row) = self.some_statement.next() {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let con = sqlite::open(":memory:").unwrap();
    let mut sqlite_controller = PreparedSqliteController::new(&con);
    sqlite_controller.exec_some_statement();
}

But it means the caller needs to build the connection for us, which IMHO kinda defeats the idea of building an abstraction.
I would really like to have the same constructor signature as the first impl : but everytime I try to build the connection from a path inside the constructor, I get some errors.
(this fails because a sqlite::Statement keeps a ref to the connection making this struct a self referential struct)
e.g :
pub struct PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    con: sqlite::Connection,
    some_statement: sqlite::Statement<'conn>,
}

impl<'conn> PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> PreparedSqliteController {
        let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
    
        Self::create_schema(&con);

        PreparedSqliteController {
            con: con,
            some_statement: con.prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap()
        }
    }

    pub fn create_schema(_con: &sqlite::Connection)  {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut _sqlite_controller = PreparedSqliteController::new(":memory:");
}

david@yoda:~/dev/rust/sqlite_prep$ cargo check
    Checking sqlite_prep v0.1.0 (/home/david/dev/rust/sqlite_prep)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `con`
  --> src/main.rs:14:9
   |
14 | /         PreparedSqliteController {
15 | |             con: con,
16 | |             some_statement: con.prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap()
   | |                             --- `con` is borrowed here
17 | |         }
   | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current 
function

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `con`
  --> src/main.rs:16:29
   |
10 |         let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
   |             --- move occurs because `con` has type `Connection`, 
which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
15 |             con: con,
   |                  --- value moved here
16 |             some_statement: con.prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap()
   |                             ^^^ value borrowed here after move

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0382, E0515.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `sqlite_prep` (bin "sqlite_prep") due to 2 previous errors

I understand the idea : when moving back the result from ::new() to the variable _sqlite_controller in main, the ref stored in the struct would not point anymore to the correct location.
I tried this, but no, does not work.
pub struct PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    con: sqlite::Connection,
    some_statement: Option<sqlite::Statement<'conn>>,
}

impl<'conn> PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> PreparedSqliteController {
        let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
    
        Self::create_schema(&con);

        PreparedSqliteController {
            con: con,
            some_statement: None
        }
    }

    pub fn create_schema(_con: &sqlite::Connection)  {}

    pub fn init(&'conn mut self) {
        self.some_statement = Some(self.con.prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut sqlite_controller = PreparedSqliteController::new(":memory:");
    sqlite_controller.init();
}

david@yoda:~/dev/rust/sqlite_prep$ cargo check
    Checking sqlite_prep v0.1.0 (/home/david/dev/rust/sqlite_prep)
error[E0597]: `sqlite_controller` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:5
   |
26 |     let mut sqlite_controller = 
PreparedSqliteController::new(":memory:");
   |         --------------------- binding `sqlite_controller` declared 
here
27 |     sqlite_controller.init();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
28 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `sqlite_controller` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `sqlite_controller` is dropped and 
 runs the destructor for type `PreparedSqliteController<'_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `sqlite_prep` (bin "sqlite_prep") due to 1 
previous error

Although here I'm a little bit skeptical : both the borrowed ref in the statement and the instance should be dropped at the same time, shouldn't it ? If so, maybe my knowledge of the borrow checker and lifetime is too limited. Is there a fix for this ?
I've read elsewhere I could maybe use some 3rd party crate (e.g : ouroboros, owningref), but how would you solve this problem with the language itself ?
Is the only way the unsafe way ?
e.g :
pub struct PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    con: sqlite::Connection,
    some_statement: Option<sqlite::Statement<'conn>>,
}

impl<'conn> PreparedSqliteController<'conn> {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> PreparedSqliteController {
        let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
    
        Self::create_schema(&con);

        PreparedSqliteController {
            con: con,
            some_statement: None
        }
    }

    pub fn create_schema(_con: &sqlite::Connection)  {}

    pub fn init(&mut self) {
        self.some_statement = unsafe {
            let ptr: *mut sqlite::Connection = &mut self.con;
            Some(ptr.as_ref().unwrap().prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut sqlite_controller = PreparedSqliteController::new(":memory:");
    sqlite_controller.init();
}

Update :
as pointed out in the comments, several issues there :

order of field destruction could in theory lead to use after free (contrary to c++, order of destruction is order of declaration)
lifetime does not make sense (well, being new to lifetime, I'm trusting the authors here as I'm not sure I make entirely sense of them yet)
the instance cannot be moved (as the refs would be lost). This is kinda ok with the current use case as expressed in the code, but it can be improved.

@user4815162342 pointed out more issues with the unsafe code and linked to this blog post that gives the full solution.
Here's an attempt for a better solution (with one caveat)
use sqlite::State;

pub struct PreparedSqliteController {
    some_statement: sqlite::Statement<'static>, // using another lifetime and annotating PreparedSqliteController would not make sense here
    _con: Box<sqlite::Connection>,              // we use Box so PreparedSqliteController.some_statement can be moved without losing the ref (*)
}

impl PreparedSqliteController {
    pub fn new(path: &str) -> PreparedSqliteController {
        let con = sqlite::open(path).unwrap();
    
        Self::create_schema(&con);
    
        let con  = Box::new(con);                        // heap allocation so refs to it outlive any move of PreparedSqliteController
        let stmt = con.prepare("SELECT 1;").unwrap();
        let stmt = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(stmt) }; // bypass the borrow checker who does not support this

        PreparedSqliteController {
            some_statement: stmt,
            _con: con,                                   // (*) problem here as we move the Box :
                                                         // could be caught by the borrow checker (MIR catches this problem)
                                                         // would need to use AliasableBox (more unsafe) to bypass it
        }
    }

    pub fn create_schema(_con: &sqlite::Connection)  {}

    pub fn exec_some_statement(&mut self) {
        while let Ok(State::Row) = self.some_statement.next() {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut sqlite_controller = PreparedSqliteController::new(":memory:");
    sqlite_controller.exec_some_statement();
}


"I've read elsewhere I could maybe use some 3rd party crate (e.g : ouroboros, owningref), but how would you solve this problem with the language itself ?" - do yourself the huge favor and use a third party crate if you need a self-referential structure. Your unsafe version has logic issues regarding its destruction.

Well, I'm very interested in knowing how the language works internally. Could you tell me what are the logic issues regarding destruction ?

You first drop the Connection and then the Statement, which can cause a UAF.

Ok, but isn't it fixable by changing the decl order of the fields ?
(note that I don't want to use unsafe if I don't have to, this is more to satisfy my curiosity)

confirmed by RFC 1857
Another solution would be to implement the Drop traits and explicitly assign to None the statements.

There are many more issues with your unsafe code. sqlite::Connection must be boxed, or moving the controller will invalidate the references. Then, it must not be in an ordinary box but AliasableBox, for technical reasons. Then, the lifetime on the struct doesn't make sense at  all, you must use Statement<'static>. See e.g. this post for details. TL;DR you almost certainly want to use something like ouroboros or self-cell for this.

Many thanks for the link @user4815162342 ! This explains a lot of the issues there !
I'm not currently using any unsafe code right now, I wrote the quick unsafe code in the post just for the sake of showing I tried to do my homework first ;)
I'll update the post with a new solution derived from the post you mentioned but without using external crates.

@DavidJobet Rust has a really minimalist/perfectionist standard library and is really not the language where one should strive to avoid "external crates" at all cost. This goes doubly when you're a beginner, the crate in question has been well whetted, and does something that's likely to be unsound if you try it yourself. As always, the decision is yours - Rust gives you the ultimate control. Disclaimer: I'm the author of that blog post.

@user4815162342 understood. As explained, I'm not using unsafe code. This is curiosity.
As a beginner in rust and a somewhat experienced developer elsewhere, I like to understand the cons/ pros of each solutions before deciding which one is good for me.
Also, I think this post serves 2 more purposes :
1- allowing other users to find a full working solution to this problem (I know I was very frustrated not finding one on stackoverflow while I would easily find solutions for other languages).
2- explain what it entails in term of safeness and the hoops one has to go through

@user4815162342 looking at self_cell, the author says : "The only reasonable safe alternative is to have the user juggle 2 separate data structures which is a mess." Do you know what he is referring to ?

@DavidJobet I guess they're referring to the solution of having a separate SqliteController (which contains sqlite::Connection) and a SqliteControllerStatement<'a> (which contains sqlite::Statement<'a>), without ever being able to bundle them together into a single coherent type.
